# Angular js when to create separate controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am implementing a functionality for (Add,update,delete & get,filter).

Currently Add View is used for add, update and delete. (Controller1)
Get View is used for get and filters. (Controller2)

Created routing for Add and Get Separately. So 2 controllers for each. 
Now i have to call service for common config  data , which is used in both the controllers.

which of the below design i should prefer.

**Design 1**

Combine both the controllers a one controller, put all the code inside.(including config data)

**Design 2**

One controller for Get ,filter
Second controller for Add, update and delete
common factory for Config data.

Am confused, which design i should prefer from all the aspects.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good practise to have "skinny controllers"

**EDIT -**

> In AngularJS, controllers can sometimes become monolithic structures of mixed business and view logic, as it’s all too easy to house anything you need for the view inside the controller. It’s convenient, and it just plain works… until your application grows in complexity or needs unit tests.
>
> **So why do we want skinny controllers, anyway?** In short, **separation of concerns**. Ideally, everything from services, to controllers, to directives, and more should be skinny, and achieving this is very possible in AngularJS. Each part should have a single responsibility and the controller’s responsibility should be to communicate between services and the view; i.e. its main concern should be view-model logic.
>
> Aim to make your controllers skinny, as well as the rest of your application, by separating out view logic and business logic into controllers and services, respectively, and by taking advantage of routes and resolves.

You can read up in detail in [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) & look at code examples

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12489485)

Comment: Thanks @GoBrewers14